# Im having trouble with turtlebot when amcl is launched I set a 2D pose, it doesn't follow a straight line and it keeps rotating in different direction

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277704/dear-all,-im-having-trouble-with-turtlebot-when-amcl-is-launched-when-i-set-a-2d-pose,-the-robot-doesn%27t-follow-a-straight-line-and-it-keeps-rotating-in-different-direction.can-someone-help-me-please-?/) by [pyth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32931/pyth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
You might find your answer here

https://answers.ros.org/question/210453/robot-rotates-instead-of-going-to-the-goal-dwa_local_planner/

---

Originally posted by [Poutchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32933/poutchi/) with karma: 16 on 2017-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0